# I want to continuous display of buttons in wpf

Tags: wpf, button, mvvm, responsive-design

In my application I have 4 button. If user will click on a button, that will disappear and remaining 3 still display.
The problem is that I don't want a control (button) gap between button.
I want remaining 3 should rearrange itself.

Which control I should use or how I can implement that. I am using MVVM in my application.

Comment: Did you use any panel to place the `Button`s ?

Comment: @ManojSingh - please see my updated answer for solution that works on all buttons.

Comment: @manoj-singh - this is getting down voted because you did not show your research.  Perhaps edit your original post to show some of the things you have tried.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 0):

Button and use [Visibility = Collapsed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visibility(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I am setting up visibility to hide clicked button. but my question is that if user will click on 3rd button then there is 1 button space is coming between 2nd and 4th button, which I don't want.

Comment: You need odd number of buttons for it to work.  New math.

Comment: could you please suggest logic for odd number ?

Comment: Why would not not try the answer in the first place?

Comment: I have tried but its not working. because I don't know which button will be clicked.

Comment: *It* works.   So you don't even know which button to hide?     Sorry, cannot help you.

Answer (score 0):

**Summary of the Solution**: I would use a `Grid` layout with automatically expanding `ColumnDefinitions` (the default setting of `Width="1*"`.  When the button is clicked and disappears (Use `Opacity="0"`), you should change the width of the corresponding `ColumnDefinition` to `0`.

Here are the before and after screen shots of what you want:

Before
[image]

After Click Donkey Button
[image]

After Click Bird Button
[image]

After Click Moose Button
[image]

After Click Giraffe Button(I accidentally resized before I screenshotted)
[image]

I know that you are using MVVM, but this problem is entirely in the user interface, so its encouraged to use code-behind for this solution.  I don't recommend putting this type of code into mvvm.

For this solution, use a grid:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Used for question 36258073" >
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="AllButton_Click"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition  Name="ColumnDefinitionNull"/>
        <ColumnDefinition  Name="ColumnDefinitionOne"/>
        <ColumnDefinition  Name="ColumnDefinitionTwo"/>
        <ColumnDefinition  Name="ColumnDefinitionThree"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Name="ButtonNull" Content="Test1 Giraffe" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
    <Button Name="ButtonOne" Content="Test2 Bird" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
    <Button Name="ButtonTwo" Content="Test3 Donkey" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" />
    <Button Name="ButtonThree" Content="Test4 Moose" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" />
</Grid>
```

and the code-behind for the button click is:

```
private void AllButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = (Button)sender;
        button.Opacity = 0;

        var zeroWidth = new GridLength(0.0);

        switch (button.Name)
        {
            case "ButtonNull":
                ColumnDefinitionNull.Width = zeroWidth;
                break;
            case "ButtonOne":
                ColumnDefinitionOne.Width = zeroWidth;
                break;
            case "ButtonTwo":
                ColumnDefinitionTwo.Width = zeroWidth;
                break;
            default:
                ColumnDefinitionThree.Width = zeroWidth;
                break;
        }
    }
```

The idea for the Opacity 0 [came from another Stack Overflow post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892494/how-can-i-make-an-invisible-yet-clickable-button-in-c-sharp).  The notion about the buttons stretching in place of the other button disappearring comes from button layout and grid definition ideas [this Stack Overflow post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27205131/auto-size-button-style), and this [Stack Overflow post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108/how-to-get-controls-in-wpf-to-fill-available-space), and [this Stack Overflow post3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462390/how-to-stretch-in-width-a-wpf-user-control-to-its-window) and this [last related Stack Overflow post4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31457590/wpf-grid-column-not-filling-remaining-space-when-other-columns-contents-are-c?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve what you need.  You have to be specific with you question.  My way of doing this would be

**xaml:**

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="Button_Click"/>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>        
    <Button Content="I am the first buttom" Margin="5"/>
    <Button Content="I am the second button" Margin="5"/>
    <Button Content="I am the third button" Margin="5"/>
</StackPanel >
```

**CodeBehind:**

```
public void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (sender as Button).Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Comment: in your solution if I will click middle one then there will be gap in between first and third. which I don't want.

Comment: @ManojSingh No. It wont leave any gap.  Try it and and let me know if there is any gap.

Comment: @Gopichandar - you have an extra end tag:  </UniformGrid.Resources> up there.

Comment: @Taterhead Edited.  Thanks for that. .

Comment: I have used WrapPanel for that, and its working as per my requirement. I have placed buttons inside WrapPannel with default attribute.

Comment: @ManojSingh I shpuld work even with stackpanel.  Anyway, glad that was working for you.